# Can I somehow affect rasterization step in webGL? (custom draw mode or something)

Tags: glsl, webgl, render

Can I somehow write custom rasterization algorithm for WebGL? What I mean:

By default in WebGL you can chose drawmode, like TRIANGLES, LINES, POINTS and so on. These modes decide which pixels should be handled by fragment shader. And the question is: can I set this rules of which pixels should be handled by fragment shader by myself?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: You can `discard` pixels in your fragmentshader

Comment: Sortof; you can draw a bounding box (two triangles) of the shape you want to rasterize, and then use `discard` in the fragment shader to draw just those pixels that fall within your rasterization rules.